# What is this Instaero folder in the root of my C: drive?

Tags: windows-10

I have bought a new PC a few weeks ago, and in the root of my C: Drive, there's this folder called Instaero that I have no idea what it's for.

Inside the folder are another folder called bootdrivers and 3 files: driver_additions.xml, partit.cmd and Start_Instaero.cmd.

Inside the bootdrivers folders, there's another folder called ke2400w10. Inside that folder are 3 files named e24w10x64, with .cat, .inf and .sys extensions.

I have no idea what these folders are, and Google weirdly enough doesn't give me any new information.

the contents of the Start_Instaero.cmd file:

```
net use R: \\assem_server\vista_pre /persistent:NO
copy /y r:\Instaero_amd64\Instaero.exe c:\Instaero
Instaero.exe
```

The contents of the partit.cmd file:

```
start /MIN \\assem_server\Vista_pre\partit\partit64.cmd
```

This could be malware, but I doubt malware would just place itself on my disk and then just not do anything.

What are these files?

Comment: Its not malware.  Its a directory used by software which is installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

#### I have no idea what these folders are

They contain drivers for a [Killer e2400 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller](http://www.killernetworking.com/products/e2200).

[image]

For more information, download and installation instructions see [Install drivers using Device Manager](http://www.killernetworking.com/product-support/knowledge-base/10-installation).

I presume the manufacturer of your PC left a copy there for some reason.

Comment: I see. I did have them install an ASUS PCE-AC86 Wi-Fi adapter. Could these be the drivers for this card?

Comment: No. That's different. These are drivers for an Ethernet card **not** a Wireless card.

Comment: You could ask the people who installed the OS for you ...

Answer (score 0):

The script looks like it copied an executable from network to the folder you specified. Do you still have that `instaero.exe` file in `C:\instaero` folder? If so, upload it to [VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com) and check for malware, check that SYS file too. Also, you can check for Publisher Information in file properties of files found in those folders, that might give you hint of the origin of this files.

After looking at the scripts, my guess is that this is some kind of configuration tool (`partit` suggests partitioning tool maybe?) that your PC manufacturer installed. But the thing that is bothering me is that it has a driver. If the files are malicious and this malicious driver is installed then you are already in deep trouble.

**EDIT:** Looks like DavidPostill already has an answer for you. You might still want to scan those files in VirusTotal, though.

Comment: there is no instaero.exe file in that folder. Those are all the files in that folder.